# animation property on svg element doesn't work on edge 15

Tags: css, svg

please see below the svg.
the animation css property works on chrome 58.
the same animation property doesn't work on edge 15.15.

what is the correct way to animate an svg element using edge?

this is the style tag i have inserted on the svg.

```
<style>
.car-container {
  transform-origin: 606px 600px;
  animation: rotate-right 6s linear 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-right {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>
```

**please see the whole svg attached in the snippet.**

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Isolation_Mode" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
  y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 1200;" xml:space="preserve">

  <symbol id="background" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200">
<style type="text/css">
 .bg0{fill:#63C6BD;}
 .bg1{fill:#EDF7F7;}
 .bg2{fill:none;stroke:#36BDB1;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:192.3119,96.156;}
</style>
<g>
 <g>
  <path class="bg0" d="M252.5,614.6H176v43h76.5V614.6z M246.7,620.4v6.9h-64.9v-6.9H246.7z M181.8,651.9v-18.7h64.9v18.7H181.8z"/>
  <path class="bg0" d="M474.5,599.1V545H143v54.1h7.1v247.2H143v27.6h331.5v-27.6h-7.1V599.1H474.5z M468.7,852.1v16H148.8v-16
   h102.7v0.2h114.6v-0.2H468.7z M251.5,776.4v70h-95.6V599.1h305.8v247.2h-95.6v-70H251.5z M360.3,782.2v64.2h-103v-64.2H360.3z
    M148.8,593.3v-42.5h319.9v42.5H148.8z"/>
  <path class="bg0" d="M447,614.6h-76.5v43H447V614.6z M441.2,651.9h-64.9v-18.7h64.9V651.9z M441.2,627.3h-64.9v-6.9h64.9V627.3z"
   />
  <path class="bg0" d="M349.8,614.6h-76.5v43h76.5V614.6z M344,651.9H279v-18.7H344V651.9z M344,627.3H279v-6.9H344V627.3z"/>
  <path class="bg0" d="M268.6,808.9H349v-22.1h-80.4V808.9z M274.4,792.6h68.8v10.5h-68.8V792.6z"/>
  <path class="bg0" d="M268.6,842.3H349V812h-80.4V842.3z M274.4,817.8h68.8v18.7h-68.8V817.8z"/>
  <path class="bg0" d="M447,667.9h-76.5v43H447V667.9z M441.2,705.2h-64.9v-19.4h64.9V705.2z M441.2,679.9h-64.9v-6.2h64.9V679.9z"
   />
  <path class="bg0" d="M349.8,667.9h-76.5v43h76.5V667.9z M344,705.2H279v-19.4H344V705.2z M344,679.9H279v-6.2H344V679.9z"/>
  <path class="bg0" d="M252.5,667.9H176v43h76.5V667.9z M246.7,705.2h-64.9v-19.4h64.9V705.2z M246.7,679.9h-64.9v-6.2h64.9V679.9z"
   />
  <path class="bg0" d="M447,721.3h-76.5v43H447V721.3z M441.2,758.5h-64.9v-19.3h64.9V758.5z M441.2,733.4h-64.9v-6.3h64.9V733.4z"
   />
  <path class="bg0" d="M349.8,721.3h-76.5v43h76.5V721.3z M344,758.5H279v-19.3H344V758.5z M344,733.4H279v-6.3H344V733.4z"/>
  <path class="bg0" d="M252.5,721.3H176v43h76.5V721.3z M246.7,758.5h-64.9v-19.3h64.9V758.5z M246.7,733.4h-64.9v-6.3h64.9V733.4z"
   />
 </g>
</g>
<path class="bg0" d="M955,670.9c-3.5,0-7,0.4-10.4,1.2c-4.1-14.9-13.2-24.7-28.2-27.8c-1.5-7.1-4.2-14-8.2-20.2
 c7.7-8.5,12-19.4,12-31.1c0-24.9-19.7-45.2-44.2-46c-4.6-11.8-26.5-16.1-46.4-16.1c-31.9,0-64.2,9.8-64.2,28.5c0,0.5,0,1.1,0,1.6
 c-13.7,7-22.4,21.2-22.4,36.8c0,4.7,0.8,9.3,2.3,13.7c-21.2,9-35,27.6-35.4,48.3c-0.6,30.4,27.3,55.7,62.3,56.4
 c7.2,0.1,20.7,0.2,41.5,0.2v152c0,1.6,1.3,2.9,2.9,2.9c1.6,0,2.9-1.3,2.9-2.9v-152c6.5,0,12.8,0,18.4,0c2.3,20.7,20.7,36.8,43,36.8
 h35v48.6c0,1.6,1.3,2.9,2.9,2.9c1.6,0,2.9-1.3,2.9-2.9v-48.6H955c23.8,0,43.2-18.5,43.2-41.2C998.3,689.4,978.9,670.9,955,670.9z
  M816.7,710.7L816.7,710.7L816.7,710.7c-0.6,0-1.1,0-1.7,0c-21.4,0-35.4-0.1-42.6-0.2c-31.8-0.7-57.2-23.3-56.6-50.5
 c0.4-19.1,13.9-36.4,34.4-44l2.9-1.1l-1.2-2.8c-2-4.5-3-9.3-3-14.2c0-13.9,8.2-26.6,20.8-32.3l1.9-0.8l-0.2-2c-0.1-1-0.1-2-0.1-3.1
 c0-14,30.3-22.7,58.4-22.7c22.9,0,39.9,5.6,41.3,13.7l0.5,2.5l3-0.1c22,0,39.9,18,39.9,40.2c0,10.9-4.2,21.1-11.9,28.7l-1.7,1.7
 l1.4,2c6.4,9.1,9.7,19.7,9.7,30.8c0,30-24.8,54.4-55.3,54.4c-3.1,0-7.7,0-13.2,0C835.7,710.7,826.3,710.7,816.7,710.7z M955,747.5
 h-74c-19.1,0-34.8-13.6-37.1-31c5.3,0,9.7,0,12.7,0c33.7,0,61.1-27,61.1-60.2c0-2-0.1-3.9-0.3-5.8c12.5,3.4,19.7,12.4,22.3,25.8
 l0.6,3.2l3.1-1c3.8-1.2,7.7-1.8,11.7-1.8c20.6,0,37.4,15.9,37.4,35.4C992.5,731.6,975.7,747.5,955,747.5z"/>
<path class="bg0" d="M1052.2,836.4c-2-9.2-10.5-15.9-20.4-15.9c-2.9,0-5.6,0.6-8.1,1.6c-3.4-6.7-8.9-12.2-15.7-15.9
 c-3.1-17.3-18.8-30.1-37.4-30.1c-17.2,0-32.1,11-36.6,26.5c-2.9-0.7-5.8-1-8.8-1c-20.9,0-37.9,16.2-37.9,36.2
 c0,19.9,17,36.2,37.9,36.2h64.3c4,0,7.9-0.6,11.6-1.7c2.3,0.8,4.8,1.3,7.4,1.3h33c11.5,0,20.9-9,20.9-20
 C1062.4,846.4,1058.5,840,1052.2,836.4z M989.5,868.2h-64.3c-17.7,0-32.1-13.6-32.1-30.4c0-16.7,14.4-30.4,32.1-30.4
 c3.4,0,6.8,0.5,10,1.5l3.1,1l0.6-3.2c2.8-14.4,16.1-24.9,31.6-24.9c16.2,0,29.9,11.4,31.9,26.6l0.2,1.6l1.4,0.7
 c6.4,3.1,11.5,8.1,14.6,14.2c-3,2.3-5.3,5.4-6.6,8.9c-1.2-0.2-2.4-0.3-3.6-0.3c-11.5,0-20.9,9-20.9,20c0,5.6,2.4,10.7,6.3,14.3
 C992.5,868,991,868.2,989.5,868.2z M1041.5,867.7h-33c-8.3,0-15.1-6.4-15.1-14.2c0-7.8,6.8-14.2,15.1-14.2c1.6,0,3.2,0.2,4.7,0.7
 l3.1,1l0.6-3.2c1.3-6.7,7.5-11.6,14.8-11.6c7.6,0,14,5.3,15,12.4l0.2,1.6l1.4,0.7c5.1,2.4,8.2,7.3,8.2,12.6
 C1056.6,861.4,1049.8,867.7,1041.5,867.7z"/>
<path class="bg0" d="M770.9,814.3h-43.5v-6.7h19.5v-22.8H728c0.2-0.4,0.2-0.7,0.2-1.2v-6h18.7v-22H595.5v22h17.6v6
 c0,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2h-17.8v22.8h16.8v6.7h-39.2v30.3h12.8v23.9c0,1.6,1.3,2.9,2.9,2.9c1.6,0,2.9-1.3,2.9-2.9v-23.9h160.6v23.9
 c0,1.6,1.3,2.9,2.9,2.9c1.6,0,2.9-1.3,2.9-2.9v-23.9h12.8V814.3z M721.6,807.5v6.7H618.1v-6.7H721.6z M601.3,761.3h139.8v10.4H601.3
 V761.3z M618.9,783.6v-6h103.5v6c0,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2h-104C618.8,784.4,618.9,784,618.9,783.6z M601.3,790.5h139.8v11.2H601.3
 V790.5z M765.1,838.8H578.9v-18.7h186.2V838.8z"/>
<path class="bg0" d="M548.1,803.4h-3.9l4.9-28.4h-46.9l4.9,28.4h-4.1c-1.6,0-2.9,1.3-2.9,2.9v61.4c0,1.6,1.3,2.9,2.9,2.9
 c1.6,0,2.9-1.3,2.9-2.9v-18.2h39.4v18.2c0,1.6,1.3,2.9,2.9,2.9c1.6,0,2.9-1.3,2.9-2.9v-61.4C551,804.7,549.7,803.4,548.1,803.4z
  M542.2,780.9l-8.4,49.3h-16.2l-4.1-23.8c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.1l-4.2-24.4H542.2z M505.8,843.8v-34.6h2.2l4.6,26.8
 h26l4.6-26.8h2v34.6H505.8z"/>
<path class="bg0" d="M1062.5,437.3H921.7l0.4-3.3c2.1-16.7,17.1-29.1,34.2-27.5c7.2-13.9,21.7-22.8,37.4-22.8
 c15.7,0,30.1,8.8,37.4,22.6c15.8,0.1,29.1,12,31.1,27.6L1062.5,437.3z M928.5,431.5h127.3c-2.9-11.2-13.1-19.3-24.9-19.3
 c-0.5,0-0.9,0-1.4,0l-2,0.1l-0.8-1.8c-6-12.8-18.9-21-33-21c-14.2,0-27.2,8.4-33.1,21.3l-0.9,2l-2.2-0.3
 C944,410.4,931.7,419,928.5,431.5z"/>
<path class="bg0" d="M665.9,393.2h92.7l-0.4-3.3c-1.9-15.7-15.3-27.5-31.1-27.6c-7.2-13.8-21.7-22.6-37.4-22.6
 c-15.8,0-30.2,8.9-37.4,22.8c-8.1-0.7-15.7,1.7-21.7,6.1c-7.2-5.5-16.1-8.6-25.4-8.6c-15.8,0-30.2,8.9-37.4,22.8
 c-17.1-1.6-32.1,10.8-34.2,27.5l-0.4,3.3h140.8l-0.4-3.3C672.8,403.7,670,397.8,665.9,393.2z M653.6,368.4l2.2,0.3l0.9-2
 c5.9-12.9,18.9-21.3,33.1-21.3c14.1,0,27,8.2,33,21l0.8,1.8l2-0.1c0.5,0,0.9,0,1.4,0c11.9,0,22,8.1,24.9,19.3h-92.7
 c-4.8-3-10.5-4.8-16.5-4.8c-2-3.8-4.5-7.2-7.4-10.1C640.3,369,646.8,367.3,653.6,368.4z M540,407.7c3.2-12.5,15.5-21.1,29.1-19
 l2.2,0.3l0.9-2c5.9-12.9,18.9-21.3,33.1-21.3c7.7,0,15,2.5,21,6.8c6.2,4.1,10.1,10.3,11.9,14.2c5.6,0.8,6.5,0.6,10.8,2.2
 c1.9,0.7,6.3,3,8.3,4.2c5.1,3,8.4,8.5,10,14.5H540z"/>
<path class="bg0" d="M959.8,325.6H768.3l0.4-3.3c2.8-22.7,23.4-39.4,46.6-36.9c9.6-19.2,29.4-31.4,50.9-31.4
 c21.4,0,41.1,12.2,50.8,31.2c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4,0c21.3,0,39.4,16,42,37.1L959.8,325.6z M775,319.8h178.1
 c-3.6-16.6-18.4-28.8-35.7-28.8c-0.7,0-1.3,0-2,0.1l-1.9,0.1l-0.8-1.8c-8.4-18-26.6-29.6-46.4-29.6c-20,0-38.3,11.8-46.6,30l-0.9,2
 l-2.2-0.3c-2-0.3-3.9-0.5-5.9-0.5C793.4,291,778.6,303.2,775,319.8z"/>
<g id="back">
 <g>
  <rect x="128.4" y="868.1" class="bg0" width="962.6" height="5.8"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <path class="bg1" d="M604,15C283.1,15,23,275.1,23,596s260.1,581,581,581s581-260.1,581-581S924.9,15,604,15z M604,1023.6
  c-236.1,0-427.6-191.4-427.6-427.6S367.9,168.4,604,168.4c236.1,0,427.6,191.4,427.6,427.6S840.1,1023.6,604,1023.6z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <circle class="bg2" cx="604" cy="596" r="505"/>
</g>
  </symbol>

<symbol id="car" viewBox="0 0 43 40.2">
<style type="text/css">
 .car0{fill:#B3E5FC;}
 .car1{fill:#FFC107;}
 .car2{fill:#FF8F00;}
 .car3{fill:#BF5300;}
 .car4{fill:#FFE082;}
 .car5{fill:#455A64;}
 .car6{fill:#546E7A;}
 .car7{fill:#FFECB3;}
</style>
<g>
 <g>
  <path class="car0" d="M6.8,10.7l-1,1.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1l-1.6-0.6c-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.1-0.4l1.6-2c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4,0
   l1,1.4C6.9,10.5,6.9,10.6,6.8,10.7z"/>
  <path class="car0" d="M10.2,6.4l-1,1.3C9.2,7.8,9,7.8,8.9,7.8L7.4,7.1C7.2,7.1,7.2,6.9,7.3,6.7l1.6-2c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4,0l1,1.4
   C10.3,6.2,10.3,6.3,10.2,6.4z"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="car1" d="M6.8,10.7l-1,1.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1l-1.4-0.5c-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.1-0.4l1.6-2C5.7,9,5.9,9,6,9.1
   l0.9,1.3C6.9,10.5,6.9,10.6,6.8,10.7z"/>
  <path class="car1" d="M10.2,6.4l-1,1.3C9.2,7.8,9,7.8,8.9,7.8L7.5,7.2C7.3,7.2,7.3,7,7.4,6.8l1.6-2c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4,0l0.9,1.3
   C10.3,6.2,10.3,6.3,10.2,6.4z"/>
 </g>
 <path class="car2" d="M22.7,6.7l-4.9-3.9c-0.3-0.3-0.9-0.2-1.1,0.1l0,0l-1.5-1.1c-1.1-0.8-2.6-0.6-3.4,0.4L2.1,14.5
  c-0.8,1-0.7,2.6,0.4,3.4l1.5,1.2l0,0c-0.3,0.3-0.2,0.9,0.1,1.1l4.9,3.9c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.2,1,0l2.7,2.3l0.6,0.4l7.8,6.2
  c-0.2,0.3-0.1,0.7,0.2,1l4.9,3.9c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.2,1,0l0,0c1.4,1,3.7,0.5,5-0.6c1.6-1.2,3.1-3.1,3.8-4c0.7-0.9,4-5,4.8-6.9
  c0.7-1.6,0.7-4-0.6-5l0,0c0.2-0.3,0.1-0.7-0.2-1l-4.9-3.9c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.2-1,0l-7.8-6.2l-0.6-0.5l-2.8-2.2C23.1,7.4,23,7,22.7,6.7
  z"/>
 <path class="car1" d="M28.4,9l-1.9,0.6c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3l-0.2,0.3L16.4,3c-1.5-1.2-3.8-0.9-5,0.6L3.4,13.8
  c-1.2,1.5-1,3.7,0.5,5l9.1,7.5l-0.2,0.3c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.5l-0.2,2c0,0,1.1,0.6,1.2,0.3l0.2-1.9c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.2
  l-0.4-0.2l0.3-0.4l13.4,10.6c1.3,1,3.6,0.4,4.9-0.6c1.5-1.2,3-3,3.7-3.9c0.7-0.9,3.9-4.9,4.7-6.7c0.7-1.5,0.7-3.9-0.6-4.9
  L26.3,10.7l0.3-0.4l0.2,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1L29,10C29.2,9.9,28.4,9,28.4,9z"/>
 <path class="car3" d="M14.7,7.3l-7,8.8c-0.4,0.6-1.3,0.7-1.8,0.2l-1.3-1C4.1,14.8,4,14,4.4,13.5l7-8.8c0.4-0.6,1.3-0.7,1.8-0.2
  l1.3,1C15,6,15.1,6.8,14.7,7.3z"/>
 <path class="car4" d="M37.9,21.7c1.2,1,1.6,2.6,1,4c-0.7,1.7-3.7,5.6-4.4,6.4c-0.6,0.8-2,2.4-3.5,3.5c-1.2,0.9-2.9,0.9-4.1,0L5.6,19
  c-1.3-1-1.5-2.8-0.5-4.1l7.8-9.8c1-1.2,2.8-1.4,4.1-0.4L37.9,21.7z"/>
 <g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <path class="car5" d="M27.3,18L20.9,26c-0.3,0.4-0.8,0.5-1.3,0.2l-5-2.9c-0.5-0.3-0.7-0.8-0.6-1.3c0.3-1.2,1-3.4,2.8-5.8
     c2.1-2.6,4-3.7,5-4.2c0.5-0.2,1-0.1,1.4,0.3l4,4.3C27.6,17.1,27.6,17.6,27.3,18z"/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <path class="car6" d="M22,12.1c-1,0.5-3,1.6-5,4.2l7.2,5.7l3.2-4c0.3-0.4,0.3-0.9-0.1-1.3l-4-4.3C23,12.1,22.4,11.9,22,12.1z"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <path class="car5" d="M35.9,25.8l-5.5,6.9c-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.6-0.4,0.7l0.3,1.2c0,0.1,0.2,0,0.5-0.3c0.6-0.7,1.9-2,3.5-4.1
     c1.8-2.2,2.8-3.7,3.3-4.5c0.2-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.2-0.5l-1.2,0C36.5,25.2,36.2,25.4,35.9,25.8z"/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <path class="car6" d="M37.6,25.8c-0.5,0.7-1.5,2.2-3.2,4.4l-1.2-1l2.7-3.5c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.6-0.6l1.2,0
     C37.9,25.2,37.8,25.4,37.6,25.8z"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <g>
   <path class="car5" d="M23,31.8l0.5-1.4c-1.8-1.6-4.1-3.4-6.5-5.2c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6,0l-0.8,0.5c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.3,0,0.4L23,31.8
    z"/>
   <path class="car5" d="M23.6,32.2l3.2,2.5c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l1,0.1c0.2,0,0.3-0.2,0.2-0.3c-0.7-0.6-2.2-2.1-4.2-3.9
    L23.6,32.2z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="car6" d="M25.8,12.9l-0.3,0.9c-0.1,0.2,0,0.4,0.2,0.6c2.3,2,4.5,3.7,6.5,5.2l1.3-0.8l-7.3-5.9
    C26,12.7,25.8,12.7,25.8,12.9z"/>
   <path class="car6" d="M32.7,20c2.2,1.6,3.9,2.7,4.7,3.2c0.1,0.1,0.3-0.1,0.3-0.2l-0.3-0.9c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3L34,19.2L32.7,20z
    "/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path class="car0" d="M2.1,14.5c-0.5,0.6-0.6,1.3-0.5,2c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.3L4,13.6c0.3-0.4,0.3-1-0.1-1.3l0,0L2.1,14.5z"/>
  <path class="car0" d="M13.6,1.3c-0.7,0-1.3,0.3-1.8,0.9L10,4.4l0,0c0.4,0.3,1,0.3,1.3-0.1l2.1-2.6C13.5,1.6,13.6,1.4,13.6,1.3z"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <polygon class="car1" points="13.6,3.7 20.5,11.4 13.1,4   "/>
  <polygon class="car1" points="3.9,15.9 13,20.8 4,15.3   "/>
 </g>
 <rect x="22.5" y="20.5" transform="matrix(0.6222 -0.7828 0.7828 0.6222 -9.175 31.9094)" class="car7" width="12" height="10"/>
 <g>
  <g>
   <path class="car2" d="M29.4,32.3l-0.2,0.2c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.1c-3.6-3.6-7-5.4-7.6-5.7c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1,0-0.2l0.2-0.2
    c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.7,0.3,4.1,2.2,7.7,5.8C29.5,32.1,29.5,32.2,29.4,32.3z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="car2" d="M35.3,24.9l0.2-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0-0.2c-4.3-2.7-6.8-5.6-7.3-6.2c0-0.1-0.1,0-0.2,0l-0.2,0.2
    c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2c0.5,0.6,3.1,3.5,7.4,6.2C35.2,25,35.3,24.9,35.3,24.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <rect x="20.3" y="22.8" transform="matrix(0.6222 -0.7828 0.7828 0.6222 -8.3977 28.4661)" class="car2" width="10" height="0.3"/>
  <rect x="21.9" y="24.1" transform="matrix(0.6222 -0.7828 0.7828 0.6222 -8.7932 30.2181)" class="car2" width="10" height="0.3"/>
  <rect x="23.5" y="25.4" transform="matrix(0.6222 -0.7828 0.7828 0.6222 -9.1887 31.9701)" class="car2" width="10" height="0.3"/>
  <rect x="25.2" y="26.6" transform="matrix(0.6222 -0.7828 0.7828 0.6222 -9.5842 33.7222)" class="car2" width="10" height="0.3"/>
  <rect x="26.8" y="27.9" transform="matrix(0.6222 -0.7828 0.7828 0.6222 -9.9797 35.4742)" class="st2" width="10" height="0.3"/>
 </g>
</g>
</symbol>

<style>
.car-container {
  transform-origin: 606px 600px;
  animation: rotate-right 6s linear 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-right {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>
  <use href="#background">
  </use>
  <g class="car-container">
  <use href="#car" width="174" height="174" class="car" transform="translate(210,281) rotate(80)"></use>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was interested in studying the issue you were having, and found this article.

https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/

Even though it's now fairly clear to me that you're not using SMIL, here was my previous response (which is still good to have on-hand, in case it's needed):

> I don't have tons of experience with what you're asking, however, "Can
>   I use..." is our friend. If you're referring to SMIL:
>
> http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20animation
>
> According to their notes, this is not planned for Edge and will
>   eventually be dropped by Chrome.  Also, here is an interesting page
>   that may help you - listing alternative, cross-compatible methods of
>   animating SVGs.
>
> https://css-tricks.com/smil-is-dead-long-live-smil-a-guide-to-alternatives-to-smil-features/

Comment: i'm not sure my example is considered as SMIL. i have added style tag inside the svg and used css3 syntax. what do u think?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Check it out.  All the comments and articles I've read so far seem to go back to GSAP, and I really wasn't interested in adding more libraries to something that would seem fundamental, however, it seems like it fixes a lot of issues and is now worth a look, imo.

Comment: ok, but still, interesting why Edge is not displaying the animation. have u seen any reference to the ability of edge to render the css command in the style tag?

Comment: figured it out eventually, i answered myself. thanks for the effort and research, i will need this javascript library probably.

Answer (score 0):

I was using animation on transform css attribute.
[edge does not currently support transforms on svg.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/supportcsstransformsonsvg/?q=Support%20CSS%20transforms%20on%20SVG)